# Extract Index of repeat value

Tags: r, dataframe

how do I extract specific row of data when the column has repetitive value? my data looks like this: I want to extract the row of the end of each repeat of x (A 3 10, A 2 3 etc) or the index of the last value

```
Name    X   M
 A      1   1
 A      2   9
 A      3   10
 A      1   1
 A      2   3
 A      1   5
 A      2   6
 A      3   4
 A      4   5
 A      5   3
 B      1   1
 B      2   9
 B      3   10
 B      1   1
 B      2   3
```

Expected output

```
 Index  Name X   M
  3      A   3   10
  5      A   2   3
  10     A   5   3
  13     B   3   10
  15     B   2   3
```

Comment: Please provide a more precise example on the desired output.

Comment: My x has a loop of 1,2,3; 1,2,3,4; 1,2,3,4,5 etc. always start at 1. I want to get the line that has the largest value within each loop. For example, the third line reaches the largest within this loop, I extract the third line. then the 5th line etc.

Comment: You may edit your question in order to show the desired output.

Comment: Edited. Appreciate your help!

Comment: @user8974334 I have made several updates to my post because you did not specify your desired output and being unclear. But I think now my output is the same as your desired output. Next time, it would be great if you can specify the desired output in the beginning.

Answer (score 1):

Using base R `duplicated` and `cumsum`:

```
dups <- !duplicated(cumsum(dat$X == 1), fromLast=TRUE)
cbind(dat[dups,], Index=which(dups))

#   Name X  M Index
#3     A 3 10     3
#5     A 2  3     5
#10    A 5  3    10
#13    B 3 10    13
#15    B 2  3    15
```

Answer (score 0):

A solution using `dplyr`.

```
library(dplyr)

df2 <- df %>%
  mutate(Flag = ifelse(lead(X) < X, 1, 0)) %>%
  mutate(Index = 1:n()) %>%
  filter(Flag == 1 | is.na(Flag)) %>%
  select(Index, X, M)
df2
#   Index X  M
# 1     3 3 10
# 2     5 2  3
# 3    10 5  3
# 4    13 3 10
# 5    15 2  3
```

`Flag` is a column showing if the next number in `A` is smaller than the previous number. If `TRUE`, `Flag` is 1, otherwise is 0. We can then filter for `Flag == 1` or where Flag is `NA`, which is the last row. `df2` is the final filtered data frame.

**DATA**

```
df <- read.table(text = "Name    X   M
 A      1   1
 A      2   9
 A      3   10
 A      1   1
 A      2   3
 A      1   5
 A      2   6
 A      3   4
 A      4   5
 A      5   3
 B      1   1
 B      2   9
 B      3   10
 B      1   1
 B      2   3",
                 header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! This might be a stupid question but I get an error message " could not find function "%>%" , do you know how to solve this?

Comment: Did you install and load `dplyr`?